# retrieve the last 100 record based on timestamp descending

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have table in database contain 10000 record,the table contain timestamp column I want to retrieve the last 100 record based on timestamp descending I use spring mvc and jpa repository Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your repository

```
List<MyEntity> findAllOrderByTimestampDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

Then, call it with

```
int queryLimit = 100;
List<MyEntity> queryResults = myRepository.findAllOrderByTimestampDesc(new PageRequest(0, queryLimit));
```

Comment: This good approach but it get first 100 record I want to retrieve the last 100 records

Comment: Just change method name to `findAllOrderByTimestampAsc`