# Retrieve the last 100 record from table

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have table in database contain 10000 record,I want to retrieve the last 100 record I use spring mvc and jpa repository Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028183/retrieve-the-last-100-record-based-on-timestamp-descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
 String hql="from <your table> order by id desc"
 Query.setMaxResults(100)
```